# Play Framework logout cookie discard java

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, logout

I am using play version 2.6.2. The application has no direct login. There is another application which will create a session and one cookie name as 
`PLAY_SESSION` and this cookie is the one I am adding in response header so that I can directly login into the Play application.

In the browser I am able to see a cookie with name `PLAY_SESSION`  and its path value is from the first application context path (e.g `"/"`).

The problem is whenever user logs out, Play will create one more cookie with the same name as `PLAY_SESSION` with a different path which is the play application context path (e.g `"/test"`). Now there are two cookies available in browser with same name but two different path values which is causing a problem.

How do I delete the new cookie which is generated by Play? I have tried with `Http.Context.current().response().discardCookie("PLAY_SESSION", "/test");`

The Logout code is like:

```
DefaultLogoutLogic<Result, PlayWebContext> logoutLogic = new DefaultLogoutLogic<>();
final PlayWebContext playWebContext = new PlayWebContext(ctx(), playSessionStore);
Result result = logoutLogic.perform(playWebContext, config, config.getHttpActionAdapter(),
        "/v3/logout-callback", null, true, true, false);
```

Any help is appreciated . Implementation is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 days and gone through source code finally got the answer , as the documentation is still not updated for play 2.6.x if somebody want to change the session path for cookie need to use play.http.session.path   instead of -

## Session configuration

```
session = {
 path = ${}
}
```

so to change the PLAY_SESSION_COOKIE session path need to use older version config property `play.http.session.path`